# Selenium: Need script to move slide up or down using keyboard and element need to be click and hold

Tags: javascript, java, c#, selenium

In my application, i need to move slider up or down.
In manual, When I click and hold the element(without release) and if i press key arrow up or down, it works fine.

I need to apply in script. Currently i tried the below script which fails to work. Could anyone please give me the solution

```
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.ClickAndHold("webelement of slider");
action.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowUp);
action.Release().Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Are you trying to bring some element into view by moving scroller and if yes, do you have id or something to locate that element? From your question, its not clear as what are you trying to achieve after scrolling.

Comment: Update the question with your relevant _HTML_ and _error stack trace_ (if any)

Comment: Did you tried using this    `Driver.FindElement("weblement of slider").SendKeys(Keys.ArrowUP)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for scrolling to bottom where scroll bar is available, as in the following code `elementIdWhereScrollerIsAvailable` is `id` of area where scroll bar is available.

`JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('elementIdWhereScrollerIsAvailable').scrollTop = window.document.getElementById('elementIdWhereScrollerIsAvailable').scrollHeight");`